# Entire Application Disappears (runs in background) instead of opening worksheet "Sheet1" in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 Userforms. In userform1, sheet to open is selected together with some textbox. In Userform2, there are additional option boxes and a command button to unload Userform2 and Activate worksheet 1 but it won't load...i used to be able to run it until i added a code to prompt user to complete fields..not sure what is wrong with my code that it won't proceed opeining the worksheet anymore

*Userform1 Code:*

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If TextBox1.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Pls. enter data"
Cancel = True
Exit Sub
End If

If Sheet1.Value = True Then
Unload UserForm1
UserForm2.Show
```

*Userform2 Code:*

```
*'to prompt user to complete fields*
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If OptionBox1.Value = False And OptionBox2.Value = False Then
MsgBox "Pls. select option"
Cancel = True
Exit Sub
End If

*'to open worksheet "Sheet1"*
If UserForm1.Sheet1.Value = True Then
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Application.Visible = True
Unload UserForm2
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the message box show when it doesnt work?

Comment: `UserForm1.Sheet1.Value ` looks suspicious.  Maybe should be one of the `OptionBox#`'s?

Comment: hi Nathan, no it just crashes but task manager shows excel is running in background. hi Chris used to work before i just added some code and lost it...not sure if is not recognizing Sheet1

Comment: i tried  hiding the If condition to isolate the problem and was able to open Sheet1 but I want to keep this line as I have other sheets to open as options not just sheet1..                                                                                            
                                                                                                                             
*'to open worksheet "Sheet1"*
'If UserForm1.Sheet1.Value = True Then   (comment)
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Application.Visible = True
Unload UserForm2
'End If  (comment)
End Sub

Comment: Isnt this condition `UserForm1.Sheet1.Value = True` true to show the form anyway?

Comment: hi nathan, i think so because Userform1 unloads and userform2 opens

Comment: im gonna go nuts if only i can do undo all my changes before i added the prompt to complete all fields it used to work earlier :(

Comment: You unload userform1 but then you try to access it from userform2 - maybe just Hide userform1?

Comment: Is `Sheet1` a control on UserForm1 ? That's a little confusing given that's the default codename for a worksheet...

Comment: @Tim Williams that fixed it! I changed "Unload Userform1" to "Userform1.Hide" and it now works!! Thank you sir!!! I was just wondering why it worked earlier but super super thanks!! now i am soo happy! you saved me from going nuts!!!have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you unload UseForm1 it's no longer accessible from UserForm2 - you should instead `Hide` UserForm1 until you're done with it, and only then `Unload` it.